# Looping over array causes crash to my program

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I made up some program that view the 7*7 table of powered by....
It's work, but from some reason the program crash at the end of the program.
My compiler is GCC and I'm using C99.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LENGTH 7

void printsTable(int arr[LENGTH][],int len);

int main()
{
    int table[LENGTH][LENGTH] = {0};
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for(j = 1; j <= LENGTH; j++)
    {
        for(i = 1; i <= LENGTH; i++)
        {
            table[j][i] = pow(j,i);
        }
    }
    printsTable(table,LENGTH);
    return 0;
}

void printsTable(int arr[][LENGTH],int len)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for(i = 1; i <= LENGTH; i++)
    {
        for(j = 1; j <= LENGTH; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: The indexing starts from 0, so you need [0, LENGTH) interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `fors` are incorrect.
Indexes starts from `0` not from `1`, in [c](/questions/tagged/c) arrays, and matrix too.

Using `<=` you are addressing out of bounds, that belongs to [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because of last loop of `i` for will point to `table[j][7]`, and last loops of `j` will point to `table[7][i]`. All those addresses are outside table allocated space, that starts from `table[0][0]` to `table [6][6]`.

You should correct your code as follow

```
for(j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++)
{
    for(i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
    {
        table[j][i] = pow(j,i);
    }
}
```

or, but not recommended,

```
for(j = 1; j <= LENGTH; j++)
{
    for(i = 1; i <= LENGTH; i++)
    {
        table[j-1][i-1] = pow(j,i);
    }
}
```

Same thing for `printsTable` function loops.

Answer (score 1):

C uses 0-based indexing for arrays.

So, for an array defined as `int table[LENGTH][LENGTH]`, the valid access index is from `table[0][0]` to `table[LENGTH -1][LENGTH -1]`.

You need to change

```
for(j = 1; j <= LENGTH; j++)
```

to

```
for(j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++)
```

to stay inside the array bounds.  Otherwise, you'll be [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). going out of bounds invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). A "crash" (or segmentation fault) is one of the side effects.